# Vim - make semicolon cycle

Tags: vim

The default behavior of `;` is to repeat the last `f`/`F`/`t`/`T` search in the same direction, and `,` moves in the opposite direction.  When they reach the last search in the line in their respective direction, continuing to press them results in a No-op.  How can I make them wrap back around so they search in a forward and backward cycle?  E.g.

`fb` a[b]c foo bar baz

`;` abc foo [b]ar baz

`;` abc foo bar [b]az

`;` a[b]c foo bar baz

Alternatively, I would also be happy with a version that started moving in the other direction once it hit the end, e.g.

`fb` a[b]c foo bar baz

`;` abc foo [b]ar baz

`;` abc foo bar [b]az

`;` abc foo [b]ar baz

Comment: You can do something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/25072966/1890567 which uses the built in search and then limits it to the current line. The n/N will wrap on the current line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought this would be fairly easy. Turns out it's not. You have to basically re-implement every single combo of `fFtT` and `;,`, with numerous edge cases. This ends up being 32 lines of vimscript. Here it is:

```
function! RepeatFind(reverse)
  let l:dict = getcharsearch()

  if a:reverse == l:dict['forward']
    let l:text = getline('.')[:col('.') - 2]
    if l:dict['until']
      let l:text = l:text[:-2]
    endif
  else
    let l:text = getline('.')[col('.'):]
    if l:dict['until']
      let l:text = l:text[1:]
    endif
  endif

  if index(split(l:text, '.\zs'), l:dict['char']) != -1
    exe 'normal! '.(a:reverse ? ',' : ';')
  else
    if !a:reverse && l:dict['forward']
      normal 0;
    elseif !a:reverse && !l:dict['forward']
      normal! $;
    elseif a:reverse && l:dict['forward']
      normal! $,
    elseif a:reverse && !l:dict['forward']
      normal! 0,
    endif
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap ; :<C-u>call RepeatFind(0)<cr>
nnoremap , :<C-u>call RepeatFind(1)<cr>
```

One difficulty comes from the uppercase variants and `,` being double-negatable, working forward. That's what accounts for lines 16-28, hardcoding all of the possible combinations.

> Alternatively, I would also be happy with a version that started moving in the other direction once it hit the end

This would probably not be very hard to implement, given that the info about last search, current direction etc. is already being stored. But it brings up some interesting corner cases. For example, what should happen if you use `;` until it switches to backwards, and then press `,`. Should that attempt going forwards and then switch backwards?

Comment: Do you know of the search function? I imagine a lot of this could be simplified if you used that. Also you can use `getcharsearch()` to figure out the search direction and the last character searched.

Comment: @FDinoff Oh wow, I did not know about that at all. That is incredibly useful, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: [Much shorter version](https://gist.github.com/Carpetsmoker/1fe1d86745a20e3bfc0e0fccfad07551). This just executes `;` or `,` and checks if the cursor moved; if it hasn't, we wrap, if it has, we don't need to do anything. IMHO this makes more sense (and it's certainly shorter!)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That version is a lot nicer. You should post it as another answer

Comment: Why do you use `<C-u>` in the mapping btw? Is that just an error/leftover from a previous version, or is there a reason from that?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Doesn't your shorter version fail if the character isn't on the line? It will move the character to the beginning of end which seem undesirable. `<C-u>` is normally used to remove `'<,'>` which are implicitly added but I don't think it makes sense for this mapping.

Comment: @FDinoff Not sure what you mean with that? But I didn't extensively test it, which is why I haven't posted it as an answer (yet).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Lets say you have are searching for `z` in the line `"line without that character"`. If you hit `;` I imagine you will go to the beginning (or end) of the line. Normally this doesn't move the cursor.

Comment: @FDinoff Right, yeah, that's a bug. Good catch :-)

Answer (score 0):

**method1**:

```
nnoremap <silent>; /\%<C-r>=line('.').'l'.
   \ getcharsearch().char<cr><cr>
```

it would type pattern like `/%<line>l<char>`, search indicated `line` and `char`.

**method2**:

```
nnoremap <silent><expr>; search(getcharsearch().char,"",line('.'))==0 ? ",,,,,,,,,,,,," : ";"
```

it would call search function in the range of current line. Call ";" jump if finding, otherwise call a lot ",,,,,,,,,," to go back fist position.

**method3**:

```
nnoremap <silent>; :let pos=col('.') <bar> 
   \exec "norm! ;"<cr>:if(pos==col('.')) <bar>
   \exec "norm ,,,,,,," <bar> endif<cr>
```

it would record the previous position. If cursor is in the end of fit position, it will type a lot ",,,,," to go back.